# Java orm problem

Tags: java, orm

There is a big table business_apply in our system. It's used to store business apply information, and contains hundreds of columns.

When business type differs, a column may mean different things.

What kind of orm framework can make our life easier? Hibernate, iBatis or something else?

Comment: but how hibernate handle such problem? create a Model class for every business types ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description you are using "wrong" DB schema:

1. table may contain hundreds (!) of columns
2. "when business type diffs ,a column may means different things"

So, hibernate is not for you. This tool is good for "right" solutions. Hibernate cannot help you too much because it cannot map your data to java object. You need some kind of custom implementation of such mapping.

I think that you need plain JDBC or a very simple helper like DBUtils from jakarta. Once you connected to DB and managed to access your big table implement a custom mechanism (probably per business) that maps bulk of your data to your value objects.

Comment: :D sorry for my English !yeah,It's almost impossible to map our DB schema to java Objects.the whole system is designed more than 10 years ago, and I am new to our company, I want make some change.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/).

Have a look at http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/scripting-sqltemplate.html
and
http://cayenne.apache.org/doc30/data-rows.html

This way you can still benefit from ORM API without sacrificing speed.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate is already a standard. This fits in almost all situations and is simple to use. I would also recommend Hibernate.

Comment: I disagree - Hibernate is not a standard; SQL is.

Comment: He has asked for ORM framework. SQL is a query language, not a orm framework.

Comment: agree with duffymo, Hibernate is widely used but it's not a standard and there are situations where it can be a good or a poor fit

Comment: JPA is a standard. Hibernate is one implementation of that standard. A very popular implementation, but not necessarily the best, and certainly not the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design sounds like it's in need of some normalization.  Columns that change their meaning depending on other columns sounds like a nightmare to understand and maintain.

With that said, I think any persistence solution can work.  Using Hibernate won't save you from the hard work of coming up with a good object model in which to map the data.  Your object model will be of a finer grain than the table(s).  You can use whatever technology you're comfortable with to get that data mapped into the objects, and loading modified objects back into the tables.

But first you have to have the objects.

Answer (score 0):

IBatis is great for letting you do manual SQL, putting you in manual control of handling table designs which perhaps don't lend themselves to proper ORM handling.

Answer (score 0):

JPA - any implementation will do. Use a single-table inheritance strategy to fit all the classes in a single table. You will need to identify a discriminator column. You should be able to use the same column in multiple subclasses to mean different things (maybe - it's worth a go, anyway).